# How do I leverage teamcity git settings

Tags: git, teamcity

I just wanted to do git push origin dev:testing as a build step. I had to jump through all kinds of hoops to get it working and making sure id_rsa files are located in the right place and settings environment variables and what have you.

We are already using git tagging which works out of the box. Is there a way to leverage the git settings with arbitrary git commands as a build step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbitrary git commands are not supported unless git is installed on the box. However in order to do git push just add one or more "Automatic merge" build features. These are run after all build steps are done, so not as flexible as build steps which can run in any order, but at least it works out of the box,